# What to put in the FAQ (the "on-/off-topic" section)?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, faq-proposed

Currently, we can modify the FAQ, but only half a section:

[image]

Therefore, most of the [`[faq-proposed]`](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) cannot be applied so far. It was recommended we just include the on- and off-topic stuff, e.g. copied from [Super User](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> … then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Any suggestions what to put there?

(BTW, just to be clear, we can also add extra sections in that area, like [cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq), but the last section must be followed by that "Please look around..." paragraph, making it hard to deviate from the on-/off-topic theme.)

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/550/suggestions-for-improving-this-faq-what-kind-of-questions-can-i-not-ask-here. Not sure which should be called the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one answered in the whole month -.- Anyway, I have written the content of FAQ. Please edit this post if you find anything unsuitable, and we would update the FAQ to reflect the change.

*[Currently the FAQ corresponds to revision **4**.]*

---

**Mathematics - Stack Exchange** is for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields.  We welcome questions about:

- Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems
- Hints on mathematical problems
- History and development of mathematics
- Solving mathematical puzzles
- Software that mathematicians use

There are certain subjects that, while still being on-topic here, you can get better response on our sister sites:

- Research-level mathematics — [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)
- Research level Algorithm design, complexity theory, etc — [Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq)
- Algorithm implementation/design, computer simulation and modelling, etc — [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
- Statistical analysis  —  [Statistical Analysis - Stack Exchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

And some kinds of questions are considered off-topic:

- Physics, engineering and financial questions — it is fine to ask the mathematical model and techniques, but concepts of the field would be off-topic.
- Typesetting equations — you can read [our guideline](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/117#117) for writing equations on this site, or visit [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com) for questions about TeX
- Numerology
- Questions about the site itself — please ask on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/) instead

If you want to get a more information of the site, you can browse our [detailed list of FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107) on meta.

Comment: "Software that mathematician uses" should be "Software that mathematicians use".

Comment: Can we remove "Software that mathematicians use"?

Comment: It would be best to put off-topic right after what is on-topic, I think.

Comment: "Physics, engineering and financial questions" could be changed to "Physics, programming, engineering and financial questions"

Comment: The part about TeX in the off-topic list could be moved to the "sister sites" thing.

Comment: @muad: (1) remove "Software that mathematicians use" — I disagree, there are over [10 questions on math.SE about software](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[math-software]+closed%3A0+wiki%3A0). It should be fine as long as it's strongly related to math. Maybe you could suggest a better wording?

Comment: @muad: (2) "put off-topic right after what is on-topic" — I arrange them in that order because it's "On topic" -> "Borderline On topic" -> "Off topic".  Could you please provide reason why changing the order is better?

Comment: @muad: (3) "Physics, programming, engineering and financial questions" — Fine, but the list may get infinitely long ;)

Comment: @muad: (4) "TeX in the off-topic list could be moved to the "sister sites" thing" — The 2nd category is not "sister sites" thing, but "border-line on-topic thing".

Comment: @KennyTM, (1) it's because there are 10 that I thought we better add this! If you want software to be on topic then that's fine but I was hoping that it wasn't.

Comment: @muad: For `[math-software]`, maybe you could voice your opinion over http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/614/. This FAQ list is not  based on my opinion, but my observation on what questions are voted up or closed, and also discussions about [allowed-questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allowed-questions) on meta.